# Google Places autocomplete for Android only capturing street

Tags: android, autocomplete, google-geocoder

I am working with Google's autocomplete widget for Android, but for some reason it appears to only be capturing the street number and name, but no other part, of the completed address.  Here is a screenshot where I entered `91 Hudson Avenue` into the autocomplete box:

[image]

Here is the snippet of my Java code which obtains the place name from the widget after a place has been selected from the drop down list:

```
@Override
public void onPlaceSelected(Place place) {
    address = place.getName().toString();
}
```

The value of `address` is always `91 Hudson Ave` *without* a city, state, or country, despite that I chose one of the options from the drop down menu.  My guess is that there is some silly configuration step which I am missing.

If you want any other information about my setup, let me know and I can edit as soon as I get a chance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you are doing this:

```
address = place.getName().toString();
```

You should be doing this:

```
address = place.getAddress().toString();
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks Pravin, this worked.  Google's own [documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/android-api/autocomplete) was using `place.getName()`, which pointed me in the wrong direction.